# Selecting MySQL data rows with an int range

Tags: mysql

Alright, for starters I am not very experienced with mysql.

The situation is as following:
I have a data table with zip code records. I need a query that finds the correct row with a zip code and number, where the table has a number range, something like this.

```
Zipcode | NumberLower | NumberUpper | Street name
1234AB  | 10          | 20          | Imaginary Drive
1234AB  | 30          | 40          | Fantasy Street
7261XY  | 2           | 4           | Rainbow Road
```

My current query is

```
SELECT * FROM zipcodetable WHERE zipcode="1234AB"
```

which returns the first two rows, as expected. What query should I use if I want to find the street name for the adress with zipcode 1234AB and number 34?

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html and find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `BETWEEN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM zipcodetable
WHERE Zipcode='1234AB'
AND 34 BETWEEN NumberLower AND NumberUpper
```

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL-related - so use single quotes for string literals, not double quotes which are generally used for JSON paths/values.